# ComboBox in ActionScript 3 (Flex)

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript, combobox, flash-builder

I have to use a menu in my actionscript project (FLARManager + Away3D) and I want to use a combobox. I try but I fail.

My simple code is

```
import spark.components.ComboBox;
import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;

public class MyComboBox extends ComboBox
{
    public function MyComboBox()
    {
        super();

        var dp_ac:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection([ 
            {label: "test 1"}, 
            {label: "test 2"}, 
            {label: "test 2"}
        ]);
        this.dataProvider = dp_ac;
        this.labelField = "label";

        this.x=200;
        this.y=-200;
        this.width=20;
        this.height=10;
    }
}
```

Then, in my project file I code:

```
import aplicacion.MyComboBox;

import artedra.*;

import com.transmote.flar.FLARManager;
import com.transmote.flar.marker.FLARMarker;
import com.transmote.flar.marker.FLARMarkerEvent;
import com.transmote.flar.tracker.FLARToolkitManager;

import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;

import spark.components.ComboBox;
import spark.components.Group;

[SWF(width="800", height="600", frameRate="30", backgroundColor="#C0C0C0")]

/**
 * 
 * @author Iago Laz
 * 
 */ 
public class ARapp extends Sprite {
    private var flarManager:FLARManager;
    private var activeMarker:FLARMarker;
    private var artedraManager:IARTeDraManager = new ARTeDraManager(stage);

    private var targetDetected:Boolean = new Boolean(false);
    private var next:Number = ARTeDraManager.GRID;

    public function ARapp () {          
        addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE,onAdded);     
    }

    private function onAdded (evt:Event) :void {
        removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE,onAdded);
        flarManager = new FLARManager("../resources/flarConfig.xml",new FLARToolkitManager(),stage);

        flarManager.addEventListener(FLARMarkerEvent.MARKER_ADDED,onMarkerAdded);
        flarManager.addEventListener(FLARMarkerEvent.MARKER_UPDATED,onMarkerUpdated);
        flarManager.addEventListener(FLARMarkerEvent.MARKER_REMOVED,onMarkerRemoved);

        flarManager.addEventListener(Event.INIT,onFlarManagerInited);
    }

    private function onFlarManagerInited (evt:Event) :void {
        flarManager.removeEventListener(Event.INIT,onFlarManagerInited);

        artedraManager.showModel();
        artedraManager.showViews();
        artedraManager.showGridDots(ARTeDraManager.GRID);

        var g:Group = new Group();
        var cb:MyComboBox = new MyComboBox();
        g.addElement(cb);

        stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN,reportKeyDown);
        stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,onEnterFrame);
    }

    private function reportKeyDown(event:KeyboardEvent):void {
        if(event.keyCode==32) {
            if(next==ARTeDraManager.DOTS)
                next=ARTeDraManager.EMPTY;
            else
                next++;
            artedraManager.showGridDots(next);
        }
    } 

    private function onMarkerAdded (evt:FLARMarkerEvent) :void {
        trace("["+evt.marker.patternId+"] added");
        activeMarker = evt.marker;
        targetDetected = true;
    }

    private function onMarkerUpdated (evt:FLARMarkerEvent) :void {
        activeMarker = evt.marker;
        targetDetected = true;
    }

    private function onMarkerRemoved(evt:FLARMarkerEvent):void
    {
        trace("["+evt.marker.patternId+"] removed");
        activeMarker = null;
        targetDetected = false;
    }

    private function onEnterFrame(evt:Event):void {
        if(activeMarker) {
            artedraManager.rotateShapes(activeMarker.rotationZ);
        }
        artedraManager.showSphereMarkerDetected(targetDetected);
        artedraManager.renderScenes();
    }
}
```

But it doesn't show anything. I think I'm missing something but I don't know what.

Can anyone help me, please?

Edit with error message:

```
TypeError: Error #1009: No se puede acceder a una propiedad o a un m賯do de una referencia a un objeto nulo.
at mx.styles::StyleManager$/getStyleManager()[E:\dev\4.x\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\styles\StyleManager.as:125]
at mx.styles::StyleProtoChain$/getStyleManager()[E:\dev\4.x\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\styles\StyleProtoChain.as:970]
at mx.styles::StyleProtoChain$/initProtoChain()[E:\dev\4.x\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\styles\StyleProtoChain.as:149]
at mx.core::UIComponent/http://www.adobe.com/2006/flex/mx/internal::initProtoChain()[E:\dev\4.x\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\core\UIComponent.as:10446]
at mx.core::UIComponent/regenerateStyleCache()[E:\dev\4.x\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\core\UIComponent.as:10509]
at mx.core::UIComponent/http://www.adobe.com/2006/flex/mx/internal::addingChild()[E:\dev\4.x\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\core\UIComponent.as:7213]
at mx.core::UIComponent/addChildAt()[E:\dev\4.x\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\core\UIComponent.as:6943]
at spark.components::Group/addDisplayObjectToDisplayList()[E:\dev\4.x\frameworks\projects\spark\src\spark\components\Group.as:1825]
at spark.components::Group/http://www.adobe.com/2006/flex/mx/internal::elementAdded()[E:\dev\4.x\frameworks\projects\spark\src\spark\components\Group.as:1416]
at spark.components::Group/addElementAt()[E:\dev\4.x\frameworks\projects\spark\src\spark\components\Group.as:1183]
at spark.components::Group/addElement()[E:\dev\4.x\frameworks\projects\spark\src\spark\components\Group.as:1141]
at aplicacion::ARapp/onFlarManagerInited()[C:\Users\Iago\workspace\PFG_ARTeDra\src\aplicacion\ARapp.as:75]
at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
at com.transmote.flar::FLARManager/onTrackerComplete()[C:\Users\Iago\workspace\PFG_ARTeDra\src\com\transmote\flar\FLARManager.as:1098]
at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
at com.transmote.flar.tracker::FLARToolkitManager/onTrackerComplete()[C:\Users\Iago\workspace\PFG_ARTeDra\src\com\transmote\flar\tracker\FLARToolkitManager.as:384]
at com.transmote.flar.tracker::FLARToolkitManager/initTracker()[C:\Users\Iago\workspace\PFG_ARTeDra\src\com\transmote\flar\tracker\FLARToolkitManager.as:332]
at com.transmote.flar::FLARManager/onTrackerInited()[C:\Users\Iago\workspace\PFG_ARTeDra\src\com\transmote\flar\FLARManager.as:1080]
at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
at com.transmote.flar.tracker::FLARToolkitManager/checkForInitComplete()[C:\Users\Iago\workspace\PFG_ARTeDra\src\com\transmote\flar\tracker\FLARToolkitManager.as:374]
at com.transmote.flar.tracker::FLARToolkitManager/onPatternsLoaded()[C:\Users\Iago\workspace\PFG_ARTeDra\src\com\transmote\flar\tracker\FLARToolkitManager.as:364]
at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
at com.transmote.flar.pattern::FLARPatternLoader/checkForLoadCompletion()[C:\Users\Iago\workspace\PFG_ARTeDra\src\com\transmote\flar\pattern\FLARPatternLoader.as:205]
at com.transmote.flar.pattern::FLARPatternLoader/onPatternLoaded()[C:\Users\Iago\workspace\PFG_ARTeDra\src\com\transmote\flar\pattern\FLARPatternLoader.as:197]
at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
at flash.net::URLLoader/onComplete()
```

Comment: Quite possibly you're adding the child *under* the viewport.  Please show more code.

Comment: If I code "addChild(cb);" or "stage.addChild(cb);" it's the same. I do this imports: "import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;" and "import spark.components.ComboBox;". When I try to put only this little code in a main function (without anymore code), it's the same, it doesen't show anything.

Comment: the question (title) is too generic... doesn't even begin to try to explain what the trouble is !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the code, I'm guessing you aren't sizing the ComboBox by setting the height and width properties or giving it a position by setting the x and y properties.

Both of these things are most commonly done in the updateDisplayList method.  In the Spark architecture updateDisplayList() is usually implemented in the skin class.

More info:

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=ascomponents_advanced_2.html

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS460ee381960520ad-2811830c121e9107ecb-7fff.html

Comment: It's the same when I set values to cb.x, cb.y, cb.width and cb.height, it doesen't show anything.

If I understood the links you post I don't need to call (or implement) updateDisplayList(), and If a property is missed (like height or width) it takes defalut values, I think.

I want to put a simple combo box (or something similar) in my project but I'm stuck here :(

Comment: You should show more code to make your question cohesive.  What is the component you're extending?  You don't need to manually call updateDisplayList(); but you should probably override it and set the the height / width / x/ y values of your ComboBox in there.  But, it depends what component you're extending.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I just edit my question with my entire code (it's an example code but I can't run it!). It's my first project in ActionScript so maybe I'm missing something important.

Comment: In the context of a Flex application; don't add anything directly onto Stage.  Add it to some container, such as the Application Tag, or a Group, or possibly even a UIComponent.  The parent is always responsible forsizing and positioning the children; so you should never set the x and y position of a component from inside the component.  Also giving a 'y' position of -200 also may place it out of the visual 'range' that you see on screen.

Comment: I tried with some x and y position values (positives and negativas) and it's the same. Now, I add Group container but it's still doing nothing :(. Well, it shows an error at runtime: `TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.` (I edited fist question to copy all error message)

Comment: @Lago Show all yor code.  Your ComboBox Extension is a great start.  Show the main application file you're using.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @www.Flextras.com I just edited my question with my main .as file where I call to MyComboBox()

Comment: @lago you're extending sprite; not the Flex Application tag.  To use Flex components in a non-Flex application, you'll have to do a lot of manual initialization of "Flex Framework" Stuff.  I understand it is doable, but tedious and undocumented.  I suggest you do not extend Sprite; but instead switch back toa "normal" Flex Application and make your main application file an MXML file that extends Application.  Or you should look for non-Flex based components to use in your app.

Comment: Thank you again for your answer. I'm not familiar in MXML files and, for this time, I think I don't have much time to learn it so I think I have to look for non-Flex based components. I want a simple menu to change my 3D model (like a combobox...), do you have any suggestion? Thank you anyway :)

Comment: @lago I would expect MXML to be extremely easy to learn for anyone w/ in depth ActionScript experience.  Even so, you can use basic MXML for the top level application, and code everything else in 100% ActionScript if you wanted to.  That said, alternate component sets are minimalComps and Reflex; I would expect they both have a ComboBox of sorts.

Comment: You helped me a lot. I was reading about MXML and yes, you're right, it's not very difficult to learn but I'm looking for a simple and easy menu (combobox) and minimalComps does it! Maybe in my next project I will use MXML. Thank you again!